# d3 - draw grid lines at specified locations

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How can I draw my grid lines at certain locations easily?

I would like to draw lines at (0, 25, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500, 750, 1k, 1.5k, 2k, 3k, 4k, 5k, 6k) vertically on the x-axis.

When using [axis.ticks()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#ticks) I do not have control where my grid lines are drawn.
I also tried to use [axis.tickValues()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues) to pass an array of the specified locations but it is not working.

**Update**:
If I use `.data(xScale.ticks(15))//FIXME` the lines are not drawn exactly above the ticks.

If I use `.data(xScale.tickValues([0, 25, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500, 750]))` instead of `.data(xScale.ticks(15))//FIXME` no grid lines are drawn.

**Update 2:** The following changes worked for me:

```
//specify where to draw all lines
var lines = [0, 25, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000];

//use your specified lines as data
.data(lines)
```

This writes exactly at the specified locations my lines.
You can either specify where to draw all lines or only values for which no ticks exist and add `.innerTickSize(-h)` which Cyril suggested

Here my code (**updated code**):

```
var w = 400;
var h = 175;
var padding = 30;

// custom scale:
var scale = [0,125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,6000];
var output = [0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350];

//specify where to draw all lines
var lines = [0, 25, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000];

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(scale)
    .range(output);

// The axis uses the above scale and the same domain:
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(scale)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

var svg = d3.select(element)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

//Create X axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+"," + (h - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);


//drawing grid lines
var bar_height = h - padding;
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lines")
    .selectAll("line")
    //.data(xScale.ticks(15))//FIXME
    //use your specified lines as data
    .data(lines)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d); })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d); })
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", bar_height);
```

Comment: How does it not work when you use `.tickValues()`?

Comment: See [this blog post](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to draw grid lines just extend the inner tick size.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(scale)
    .innerTickSize(-h)//for extending  the grid line
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/qgdwvse1/)

**EDIT**

For hiding a few ticks you can do like this:

```
//define scale and its related domain like this.
var scale = [0,25,50,100, 125,250,500,750,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000];
var output = [0,20, 40, 80, 100,200,300,340,400,500,550,600,650,700];
//define ticks that not be displayed this means ticks will not be drawn for the array.
var scaleTicksNotDisplay = [250, 3000,5000]
```

Define the xaxis tickformat with a condition like this:

```
// The axis uses the above scale and the same domain:
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(scale)
    .innerTickSize(-h)
    .tickFormat(function(d){
      if (scaleTicksNotDisplay.indexOf(d)>=0){
       return "";//return blank for ticks inside scaleTicksNotDisplay
      } else {
         return d3.format("s")(d);
      }

    });
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/8gqxvwvt/2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: downvoter appriciate if you can explain what you didn't like in my answer so that i can make it better... Thanks!

Comment: At first sight it didn't occur to me that this does actually provide an answer to the question, which is why I downvoted the answer. However, I was in error but the vote was already locked. I did a minor edit followed by an immediate rollback to unlock it again, and turn this into an upvote, though. Sorry for the confusion and me messing around with your revision history ;-)

Comment: Cool trick to draw the line from the y-coordinate 0 above every ticks by going down -height of the svg. However, with this I can only draw lines above defined ticks. But what about lines above not defined ticks (25, 50, 100, 150, 750, 1.5k, 3k, 5k according to the data of my example)?

Comment: @jack check my update in the edit section in my answer above.

Comment: Cool, this reduces the code extremely. @Cyril Do you know if it is possible to draw the lines with .innerTickSize(-h) but also having the default behaviour .innerTickSize(6) i.e. to also see a small tick that goes down?

Comment: Nopes no idea about that :(